# What do I need to keep in Proguard to run ObjectDB?

Tags: exception, factory, objectdb

I am using [Proguard](https://www.guardsquare.com/en/proguard) to minimize the size of my shaded/uber Jar.  This was working great until I included a dependency on [ObjectDB](http://www.objectdb.com/).  What do I need to keep to make ObjectDB work?

I am getting the following output when calling `Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory()`.

```
javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProviderResolverHolder$DefaultPersistenceProviderResolver log
WARNING: javax.persistence.spi::No valid providers found using:
javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProviderResolverHolder$DefaultPersistenceProviderResolver log
WARNING: javax.persistence.spi::com.objectdb.jpa.Provider - jar:file:/C:/Documents/JProjects/TimeClock/target/TimeClock-1.5.0.jar!/META-INF/services/javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider

javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named db.odb
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:85)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:54)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following Proguard option:

```
-keep class com.objectdb.jpa.Provider {<fields>; <methods>;}
```